# Smallest $k$ to make sure the $k$-nearest-neighbor graph is connected

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, machine-learning, path-connected

Given any $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then make an undirected edge between every point and each of its $k$ nearest neighbors (in Euclidean distance).  What is the smallest $k$ to make sure that the graph is (path) connected? I guess $k$ is a function of $n$, but it could also depend on $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Cool Question. First, note that $k > \lfloor \frac{n}{2} -1 \rfloor$ since you can split the $n$ points into two "far apart" sets both having size size $\geq  \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ yielding two disjoint graphs. To see that this is the worst case, apply [dirac's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=Dirac%27s%20theorem%20on%20Hamiltonian%20cycles,all%20minimal%20separators%20are%20cliques) (any $n$ vertex graph with all degrees  $ \geq n/2$ is Hamiltonian, and thus connected).